# Intell IJ IDEA: illegal character \u00bb'

Tags: intellij-idea

IntellIJ Idea 2019

In my java file:

```
package com.java.testproject.java.TestProjectJava.leetcode;

public class TwoSum {

    public TwoSum() {

    }
}
```

Here client code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("Current date: " + new Date());
        System.out.println();

        new TwoSum();
}
```

But When compile I get error:

[image]

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe file is saved with Unicode BOM?

Comment: Yes, after change , to "with no BOM", then success run. What is wrong with BOM ?

Comment: Some editors have issues with it. Specifically, with UTF-8 BOM. You can find more at [What's the difference between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)